# vb net Unable to load DLL 'SQLite.Interop.dll

Tags: vb.net, sqlite

I am working on a Windows 7 64 bit computer with VS 2019 ver 16.7.5 and Net.Framwork ver 4.8.03761
I am getting this error
System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load DLL 'SQLite.Interop.dll': The specified module could not
be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)
at System.Data.SQLite.UnsafeNativeMethods.sqlite3_config_none(SQLiteConfigOpsEnum op)
at System.Data.SQLite.SQLite3.StaticIsInitialized()
at System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteLog.Initialize(String className) 
at System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteConnection..ctor(String connectionString, Boolean parseViaFramework) 
at System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteConnection..ctor(String connectionString)

I am using the same code to create a DB and DB Table that I used in a project a few months ago
It still works as expected the DB and DB Table are created
I started a New Project and coped and pasted the code to create the DB and DB Table from the older Project NOW I HAVE this ERROR which makes no sense to me. I am not trying to package the app
I am using PackageReference and do not see ApplicationEvents.vb folder in the new Project
It is present in the older project

I am not sure what is broken or how to FIX this issue
I have seen some other SO Posts but these deal with Packaging the app in an EXE file

Here is the code

```
Imports System.Data.SQLite

Public Class frmStart
    Public connStr As String = "Data Source={0};Version=3;"
    Public conn As SQLiteConnection

    Private Sub frmStart_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        Icon = Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon(Application.ExecutablePath)
        connStr = String.Format(connStr, gv_dbName)

        If My.Computer.FileSystem.FileExists(gv_dbName) Then
            frmMenu.Show()
            Close()
        ElseIf Not My.Computer.FileSystem.FileExists(gv_dbName) Then
            tbMessage.Text = "Create Database & Table"
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnCreate_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCreate.Click
        makeDB()
    End Sub
    Public Sub makeDB()

        If Not My.Computer.FileSystem.FileExists(gv_dbName) Then
            Try
                conn = New SQLiteConnection($"Data Source = '{gv_dbName}';Version=3;")
                conn.Open()
                makeLabelTable()

            Catch ex As Exception
                'tbMessage.Text = "Database NOT Created"
                tbMessage.Text = ex.ToString

            End Try
            conn.Close()
            'ERROR is thrown in line of code above
            '=====================================
        End If

    End Sub
    Public Sub makeLabelTable()

        'create table LabelTable String for cmd
        Dim create_table As String = String.Empty
        create_table = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS LabelTable(
                        TID INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
                        tFname NVARCHAR(50),
                        tLname NVARCHAR(50),
                        tAddress NVARCHAR(50),
                        tCity NVARCHAR(50),
                        tState NVARCHAR(50),
                        tZip NVARCHAR(50),
                        tFontSize NVARCHAR (500))"

        Dim dbTable As String = "LabelTable"

        If Not My.Computer.FileSystem.FileExists(dbTable) Then
            Try
                Using conn As New SQLiteConnection(connStr)
                    conn.Open()
                    Using cmd As New SQLiteCommand(create_table, conn)
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                    End Using
                End Using
                conn.Close()
                frmMenu.Show()
                Close()
            Catch ex As Exception
                tbMessage.Text = "Label Table FAILED"
            End Try
        End If

    End Sub
```

**This is an EDIT with a very useless SOLUTION

I copied the x86 and x64 files from the older project and pasted into the

new NON FUNCTIONING project so now it finds the Interop.dll

But this makes the Question

Why do I need to copy and paste these file to the project?**
If they are needed they should get added automatically
I did not copy and paste these files in the older project what changed?
**How do you add these files without doing a copy and paste ?**
Here is a Screen Shot FWIW
[image: Screen Shot]

Comment: [Install and manage packages in Visual Studio using the NuGet Package Manager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/install-use-packages-visual-studio) Then: https://www.nuget.org/packages/system.data.sqlite/

Comment: @dr.null thanks for the link but too many options so I have System.Data.SQLite.Core installed on the older project and it works fine I guess you are suggesting I use SYstem.Data.SQLite I will try it but that was not my choice ?

Comment: If you don't have the package installed globally then I advice you to follow the links. Run the command in the NuGet Package Manager Console in your IDE to download (or update if you already have) the latest version for the current project. This way the IDE and the compiler will do the necessary to locate and link the right assemblies.

Comment: @dr.null I have never installed the System.Data.SQLite.Core globally I have an app that I created an EXE file for that uses System.Data.SQLite.Core installed on the machine Will try to update System.Data.SQLite.Core from NuGet PM

Comment: I don't quite see where the database is being created. Does the mere attempt to open a connection create it? I saw this `SQLiteConnection.CreateFile("MyDatabase.sqlite")`

Comment: You need to copy the required assemblies to the current output (EXE) folder including the `x86` and `x64` folders that contains the `SQLite.Interop.dll` files for each. That's what the NuGet will do for you. If you prefer to do it yourself, copy the SQLite.XXX files and the mentioned two folders from the old project.

Comment: @Mary The makeDB in the older project Creates the DB then the Table

Comment: @dr.null I have no need for the two folders x86 and x64 I am not making a EXE file I am only trying to create a DB and a Table

Comment: @dr.null See my update to the question So my real question is how to do this with the IDE or Why is it not being handled when the System.Data.SQLite.Core is added ?

Comment: Because this is how it is. Read [this](https://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/downloads.wiki) please.

Comment: @dr.null I did read and this statement makes it sound as though x64 & x86 get installed with the Nuget install that did not happen in my case This NuGet package contains all the binaries for both the x86 and x64 versions of System.Data.SQLite 1.0.113.0 (3.32.1 I tried this with a new project same issue NO x64 or x86 installed

Comment: It's broken in System.Data.SQLite.Core.1.0.112.2. It did work in System.Data.SQLite.Core.1.0.112.1.

Comment: @Alpha01 I had  System.Data.SQLite.Core.1.0.112.2. installed and in testing another app with this version installed it demanded I do an update to  System.Data.SQLite.Core.1.0.113.3 Not sure if this is the issue with SQLite.Interop.dll not being installed or should I say not creating x64 and x86 folders with Interop.dll